# why does left join is not giving all left table value with null values of other table where condition is getting false?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this-

[image]

Expected Output is -:

[image]

I am getting the exact result with this query-:

```
select a.city as source,nullif(b.city,a.city) as destination from TABLENAME a,TABLENAME b
```

But I dont wanna use any sql function in my query, so I tried this one -:

```
select a.city as Source,b.city as Destination
from testq a left join testq b
on a.city<>b.city
```

Using this query I am getting -:

[image]

I know that I am doing very silly mistake somewhere but I am stuck here and now not getting. Please help me if you can get that thing.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *"But I dont wanna use any sql function in my query"* Why not?

Comment: bcoz someone asked me to do so.

Comment: And why did they ask you do so? Is this an interview question? Why are they saying you can't use a function, when clearly it's the right choice here.

Comment: not an interview question, my friend asked me

Comment: Then i would respond with `NULLIF` is the correct function to use here. Avoiding a function would only make the query more complex and possibly confuse the end user. I can't see a good reason your friend is opposed to `NULLIF`.

Comment: @Larnu I know all these things which you are telling me, if you know what I asked for thn respond.

Comment: I have, @Ishubh; but it does seems some very odd logic.

Comment: This is a terrible question - how do I do this thing, but don't tell me *any of the right ways* to do it, since they're "not allowed"...

Comment: @aaron first, no body forced u you to give answer to my question. second, I knew the best way at first and I mentioned that to in my question "if u can see". But I had some constraints that's y I asked for a tricky way to do that to a tricky smart guy "definitely not to you" OKAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to use any function, CASE clause might work for you here -

```
 SELECT a.city as source, CASE WHEN a.city = b.city THEN null ELSE b.city as destination
 FROM TABLENAME a
 CROSS JOIN TABLENAME b
```

Comment: You realise this is actually identical to the `NULLIF` version right? `NULLIF` is a short hand `CASE` expression; so it is actually identical to the OP's SQL in the question. I'm not saying that this is therefore "wrong", but it makes no sense that this is the accepted answer when it's actually (from the RDBMS' point of view) exactly the same. [`NULLIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/nullif-transact-sql): *"NULLIF is equivalent to a searched CASE expression in which the two expressions are equal and the resulting expression is NULL."*

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comments, I can't see any problems with the query you have, other than do use ANSI-92 syntax:

```
SELECT TN1.city AS source,
       NULLIF(TN2.city, TN1.city) AS destination
FROM TABLENAME TN1
     CROSS JOIN TABLENAME TN2;
```

If, for reasons unknown, you must not use `NULLIF` you could do something odd like this; but i see no reason why you would:

```
SELECT TN1.city AS source,
       TN2.city AS Destination
FROM TABLENAME TN1
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT ca.city
                  FROM TABLENAME ca
                  WHERE ca.city != TN1.city
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT NULL) TN2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `union all`?

```
select c.city, c2.cty
from cities c join
     cities c2
     on c.city <> c2.city
union all
select c.city, null
from cities c;
```